# Why i can't directly write R.styleable.SeekBar_thumb?

Tags: java, android, android-xml, android-styles

When trying to use in my code **any** *View* attribute using the R.styleable.someAttribute for example R.styleable.SeekBar_thum, android studio doesn't recognise it, marks it in red and saying: "can not resolve symbol 'SeekBar_thumb'.
Can someone explain me what is the problem? because with my customs view it works great.
I hope someone can clarify me the issue.
Thanks in advance